# Refactor if and else statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a if else statement that I would like to refactor. I've seen some examples online but I haven't found one that could help me. I'm still learning.

```
condition 1

if(p.timestamp === p.lastTimeStamp)
then let postData = {
  room: p.room,
  patient: p.id,
  timestamp: p.timestamp,
}
```

```
condition 2

if (p.timestamp !== p.lastTimeStamp) 
then the postData will have one extra key that is replace : p.lastTimeStamp

let postData = {
  room: p.room,
  patient: p.id,
  timestamp: p.timestamp,
  replace : p.lastTimeStamp
}
```

My current function looks like below. I would appreciate if you could give me idea of how to refactor the below.

```js
postRecord(patient) {
  this.state.patients.map(p => {
    let postData = {};
    if ((p.id === patient.id) && (p.timestamp !== p.lastTimeStamp)) {
      postData = {
        room: p.room,
        patient: p.id,
        timestamp: p.timestamp,
        replace: p.lastTimeStamp
      };
    }
    if ((p.id === patient.id) && (p.timestamp === p.lastTimeStamp)) {
      postData = {
        room: p.room,
        patient: p.id,
        timestamp: p.timestamp,
      };
    }
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/record',
        data: postData
      })
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          recordSuccess: (res.status === 200)
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        throw new Error(err);
      });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just conditionally add to the object:

```js
let postData = {
  room: p.room,
  patient: p.id,
  timestamp: p.timestamp
};
if (p.timestamp !== p.lastTimeStamp) {
  postData["replace"] = p.lastTimeStamp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and get the wanted parts.

```
let postData = {};
if (p.id === patient.id) {
    postData = p.timestamp === p.lastTimeStamp
        ? { room: p.room, patient: p.id, timestamp: p.timestamp }
        : { room: p.room, patient: p.id, timestamp: p.timestamp, replace: p.lastTimeStamp };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify the condition by assigning the extra property with a check as your object won't change apart from that one property:

```js
let postData = {};
if (p.id === patient.id) {
  postData = {
    room: p.room,
    patient: p.id,
    timestamp: p.timestamp
  };
  if (p.timestamp !== p.lastTimeStamp)
    postData['replace'] = p.lastTimeStamp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You havent got an if/else there - you've got 2 if statements that will both always run. If you are simply after an if else statement:

```
if ((p.id === patient.id) && (p.timestamp !== p.lastTimeStamp)) {

            postData = { 
                room: p.room,
                patient: p.id,
                timestamp: p.timestamp,
                replace: p.lastTimeStamp
            };
        } else {

            postData = { 
                room: p.room,
                patient: p.id,
                timestamp: p.timestamp,

            };
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

without ternary operator:

```js
let postData = {};
if (p.id === patient.id) {
    if (p.timestamp !== p.lastTimeStamp) {
        postData = {
            room: p.room,
            patient: p.id,
            timestamp: p.timestamp,
            replace: p.lastTimeStamp
        };
    } else {
        postData = {
            room: p.room,
            patient: p.id,
            timestamp: p.timestamp,
        };
    }
}
```